# x86 function returning char* in C

Tags: c, assembly, x86, nasm, inline-assembly

I want to write a function in x86 which will be called from C program.
The function should look like this:

```c
char *remnth(char *s, int n);
```

I want it to remove every nth letter from string s and return that string. Here's my remnth.s file:

```
section.text
global remnth

remnth:
; prolog
    push ebp
    mov ebp, esp

; procedure
    mov eax, [ebp+8]; Text in which I'm removing every nth letter
    mov ebx, [ebp+12]; = n
    mov ecx, [ebp+8] ; pointer to next letter (replacement)


lopext:
    mov edi, [ebp+12]     ; edi = n  //setting counter
    dec edi               ; edi--  //we don't go form 'n' to '1' but from 'n-1' to '0'
lop1:
    mov cl, [ecx]         ; letter which will be a replacement
    mov byte [eax], cl    ; replace
    test cl,cl            ; was the replacement equal to 0?
    je exit               ; if yes that means the function is over
    inc eax               ; else increment pointer to letter which will be replaced
    inc ecx               ; increment pointer to letter which is a replacement
    dec edi               ; is it already nth number?
    jne lop1              ; if not then repeat the loop
    inc ecx               ; else skip that letter by proceeding to the next one
    jmp lopext            ; we need to set counter (edi) once more 

exit:
; epilog

    pop ebp     
    ret
```

The problem is that when I'm calling this function from `main()` in C I get Segmentation fault (core dumped)

From what I know this is highly related to pointers, in this case I'm returning `*char`, and since I've seen some functions that returns `int` and they worked just fine, I suspect that I forgot about something important with returning a `*char` properly.

This is what my C file looks like:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

extern char *remnth(char *s,int n);

int main()
{
    char txt[] = "some example text\0";

    printf("orginal = %s\n",txt);
    printf("after = %s\n",remnth(txt,3));

    return 0;
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Which C calling convention are you using? The code above adheres neither to Microsoft nor unix conventions.

Comment: @RaymondChen linux (unix), can it be that the problem is there?

Comment: Read about the register preservation rules for linux. Specifically, you are not preserving ebx or edi.

Comment: @RaymondChen I've added pushing ebx,edi,ecx on stack and popping them and now at least I don't have a SegFault but blank text is displayed. Guess my function isn't valid

Comment: Two pieces of advice: (i) write and test the function in C first, to check that your logic is correct; (ii) learn how to use your debugger to step through the assembler code.

Comment: Try a simpler program that just calls `remnth` and stores the result in a variable. Then look in the debugger to step through the function as well as seeing what got returned. +1 to @TonyK. There is already a computer program whose purpose is to take C code and convert it to assembly. It's called a compiler.

Comment: It looks like you're returning a pointer to the *end* of the new string.  That's actually a good thing; the caller already knows what address it passed for the start.  So this lets it calculate the length, e.g. to pass it to a `write` system call or other explicit-length use.  Don't throw away work (like finding the length); the design of C functions like `strcat` are a bad model, they're hard to use efficiently.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using `ecx` as a pointer, and `cl` as a work register.  Since `cl` is the low 8 bits of `ecx`, you're corrupting your pointer with the `mov cl, [ecx]` instruction.  You'll need to change one or the other.  Typically, `al`/`ax`/`eax`/`rax` is used for a temporary work register, as some accesses to the accumulator use shorter instruction sequences.  If you use `al` as a work register, you'll want to avoid using `eax` as a pointer and use a different register instead (remembering to preserve its contents if necessary).

Comment: Thank You! Even though I was looking at how registers are organized, I didn't realize what mistake I made. I need to be less clumsy asap.

Answer (score 1):

You need to load the return value into eax before the return. I assume you want to return a pointer to the beginning of the string, so that would be `[ebp+8]`.

Comment: Thank You! I don't know why but I somehow assumed that pointer to the beginning of the string was kept in ```eax```. I totally forgot that I was incrementing it.

Comment: Returning a pointer to the *end* of the new string is actually a good thing; the caller already knows what address it passed for the start.  So this lets it calculate the length, e.g. to pass it to a `write` system call or other explicit-length use.  Don't throw away work (like finding the length); the design of C functions like `strcat` are a bad model, they're hard to use efficiently.  [strcpy() return value](//stackoverflow.com/a/51547604) explains why `strcpy` is dumb and `stpcpy` makes more sense.